# Format (Y-m-d H:i:s) in swift 3 returns nil

Tags: date, swift3, date-format

I'm using this function

```
 func getDateFromString(date: String) -> Date
{

    let dateFromatter  = DateFormatter()
    dateFromatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFromatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC-2")
    let date = dateFromatter.date(from: date)

    return date!
}
```

and it works well and returns date as for example : `2017-07-01 22:00:00`, 
but when I change the formate to `dateFromatter.dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s"`
it returns `nil`. 
How to solve this issue and get the date in this format `Y-m-d H:i:s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically both formats PHP `Y-m-d H:i:s` and Cocoa `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` are identical but Cocoa does only consider its own format.

So since *it works well* what's wrong with the Cocoa format?

Comment: I don't got your mean.. the target format works with you ??

Comment: In PHP `Y-m-d H:i:s` creates `2017-07-01 22:00:00`, in Cocoa `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` creates `2017-07-01 22:00:00`. There is no difference, but you must not use the PHP format specifiers. You have to use the Cocoa (Unicode) format specifiers which match the passed string.

Answer (score 0):

The date formatter formats use the [Unicode technical standard 35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). It appears from reading that that, `i` is not a valid format specifier, so your date format is invalid. You need to figure out which valid specifiers give you the format you want.